# Why am I seeing SSL events resolve to OpenDNS IPs?

Tags: dns

This organization I'm working for uses OpenDNS/Cisco Umbrella. I'm confused as to why I'm seeing requests for SSL traffic resolved to

```
146.112.255.155
146.112.250.83
146.112.250.64
146.112.250.87
146.112.250.73
```

Are these sinkholed IP addresses? I thought the blockpage IPs were these ones: https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227986927-What-are-the-Cisco-Umbrella-Block-Page-IP-Addresses-

I guess I'm just confused as to how this whole thing works. I've tried reading the OpenDNS support but it hasn't really answered my questions on the IPs above.

Comment: You mean HTTPS traffic? When do you see that? When accessing some blocked pages ?

Comment: Yes sorry, I did mean HTTPS traffic. I'm seeing the traffic throughout the day. I'm assuming these OpenVPN IPs are of their block pages? I know they belong to OpenVPN, I'm just not sure of their purpose.

Comment: Maybe OpenVPN could explain that to you if you ask them...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your company is using Cisco Umbrella Intelligent Proxy (Selective Proxy) or Secure Web Gateway (Full Proxy), and is decrypting SSL traffic.

This tunnels all web traffic through Umbrella Data Centres and forms a MITM (man in the middle) SSL connection between you and the HTTPS domain.

Therefore your certificates will be issued from the Umbrella Data Centres as opposed to the domain destination.

https://docs.umbrella.com/umbrella-user-guide/docs/cisco-umbrella-data-centers